# Application that connects to node REST api is being blocked by customers firewall

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets

My company and I is developing an angular application that gets its data from our own build API.

The API is build in `node.js` using `express` and runs on port `8080`.

We sell licences to medium sized / huge companies.

A common problem we have with our clients is that once they try to log in to the system they get rejected (by their own firewall) because it does not allow traffic on port `8080`. Which means that each of our clients will have to run by their own IT department to get our system to work.

This is of-course  always a bad start with new clients.

So my question is: is there a way to avoid this either by choosing a "safer" more common port or am i doomed to have this embarrassing remark on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you can simply use port `80`. It is the most commonly used port for HTTP. Or `443`, the most commonly used port for HTTPS. They are probably the most likely ports not to be blocked by firewalls.

Comment: if i use these ports will people with port 80 already in use be able to connect to my system?

Comment: I don't think you understand how ports work. Clients can connect to many applications that use port 80. Almost every single website you visit uses port 80. The question is, is port 80 already in use on your server? You can't have two server-side applications both listening on port 80. But if you only have one express app on the server then it's not a problem.

Comment: Guys, this is not just about ports. The firewalls parses entire corporate traffic, even HTTPS (by re-signing with pre-trusted certificate). So it analyzes HTTP internals. e.g. this is why connections dropped in case if this is not a HTTP at all (e.g. when people trying to pass SSH over 80 or 443). I have very similar problem, a legit Angular2+NetCore app get's blocked automatically on corporate firewall for many customers. They see a page once, REST api is not working and on a next visit or refresh - entire web site is blocked. I've seen it from many offices for many similar apps.